# MemoryError in reading word2vc data file to python

Tags: python, memory, word2vec

I am trying to use word2vec in Windows 7. I have 24GB of RAM, and i7 processor, and I am using 64-bit python. I am trying to follow the tutorial by Radim. I want to access the vectors in the google 3 billion file provided by the word2vec original page.
When I run the line:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.10.1-py2.7.egg\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 536, in load_word2vec_format
result.syn0 = zeros((vocab_size, layer1_size), dtype=REAL)
MemoryError
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem since the file is only 1.3GB and I have plenty of free memory space.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Python? 32-bit Python can only access 4GB of RAM at the very most.

Comment: it is a 64-bit python.

Comment: I wonder how big `vocab_size` and `layer1_size` are. If they are both in the millions, it would easily exceed your available memory (even with 24GB of RAM).

Comment: The layer1_size=300, and the vocab_size should be at max 200K, since it is the size of English vocabulary, at most.

Comment: Yeah, that's maybe only 480MB...hm, it is kind of weird.